# Passing javaScript object to modal, convert List<Obj> and passing to JS not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, modal-dialog

I have a JSP with table and rows. Hyperlink in one column is a POJO list which when clicked should open up a modal window. Below is the code.

```
<td><%if(folderStrutList.getFileCount() != 0) {%><a href="javascript:openModalShowFileList(<%=fileList%>)"><%=folderStrutList.getFileCount()%></a><%}else{%><%=folderStrutList.getFileCount()%><%}%></td>
```

JavaScript code is

```
function openModalShowFileList(fileList) {
    alert(fileList);    
    openModalCreateFiles();
}

function openModalCreateFiles() {   
    openGenModelPopUp('MaskedDiv','ModalPopupOpenFiles');   
}

function openGenModelPopUp(primary, secondary)
{                  
  document.getElementById(secondary).style.visibility='visible';
  document.getElementById(secondary).style.display='';                 
  document.getElementById(secondary).style.top= Math.round ((document.documentElement.clientHeight/2)+ document.documentElement.scrollTop)-180 + 'px';
  document.getElementById(secondary).style.left=Math.round ((document.documentElement.clientWidth/2))-450 + 'px';
  document.getElementById(secondary).style.display='';
  document.getElementById(primary).style.visibility='visible';
  document.getElementById(primary).style.top='0px';
  document.getElementById(primary).style.left='0px';
  document.getElementById(primary).style.width=  document.documentElement.clientWidth + 'px';
  document.getElementById(primary).style.height= document.body.clientHeight+ 'px';      
}
```

the masked div is an included JSP like,

```
<%
    Utility myUtil = new Utility();
    String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
%> 

<script>

function CloseGenModelPopup(primary, secondary)
{
    document.getElementById (primary).style.display='none';
    document.getElementById (secondary).style.display='none';                 

}        
</script>
<div id="MaskedDiv" class ="MaskedDiv"></div>   
<div id="ModalPopupOpenFiles" class="ModalPopup">
  <div id="divHeader">
    List of Files in this Folder:
  </div>
  <br>
  <form name="fileList" method="POST">
    <table></table>
  </form>
</div
```

This being legacy code cant use jQuery modal. I am so confused on how to pass this `<%=fileList%>` to modal window. I need not go to servlet to get the resultset. I have resultset already in `List<fileList>`. This is not a static one, this value would change dynamically. Please suggest how to proceed.

With the current code, I am not even able to call JS since it tells me UnCaught syntax error.

generated view source for filelist with one object is,

```
<a href="javascript:openModalShowFileList([com.abc.Files@6a145f56])">1</a>
```

Comment: The key is to realize, **where** and **when** which code is executed - JSP on the server, when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is sent to the browser), and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response.

Comment: @Jozef Chocholacek modal is loaded but masked when JSP loads up. So the getAttribute in that modal is null initially. button click ajax call and setAttribute wouldnt have any effect when the modal opens up because its already loaded when JSP is rendered is it.  Is there any other option to render in the modal through ajax ?